# Javascript change property inside object within array logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

```
        case ActionTypes.ADD_TO_CART: {
        var newOrders = state.cartItems.slice();
        let updatedIem = state.cartItems.find(i => {
            if (i.id === action.product.id) {
                return action.product
            }
            else {
                return null
            }
        });
        if (updatedIem) {
            var oldOrder = newOrders[action.itemIndex];
            var newOrder = Object.assign({}, oldOrder);
            if (action.direction == 1 && newOrder.quantity > 0) {
                newOrder.qty++;
                newOrder.quantity--;
            }
            else if (action.direction == -1 && newOrder.qty != 0 && newOrder.quantity > 0) {
                newOrder.qty--;
                newOrder.quantity++;
            }
            else null

            newOrders[action.itemIndex] = newOrder;
        }
        else {
            newOrders[action.itemIndex] = action.product
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            cartItems: newOrders,
        };
    }
```

This code returns an Array `cartItems` in the returned object but the problem is that one of Array elements is `undefined`, as in: `[{first object}, undefined, {third object}]`.

The `undefined` element is not wanted. I know it's coming from one of the assignments to `newOrders[action.itemIndex]` but I don't know how to track this down.

Comment: Can you please add some punctuation? Also, can you please state your question explicitly?

Comment: What is `state`? please upload your executable code!

Comment: const INITIAL_STATE = {
    cartItems: []
};

here is the state i use 

and here is the action  dispatch(CartActions.addToCart(newOrder, direction, itemIndex))

i just wanna go away and not using indexes and using id's instead

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to approach this problem:

(1) Make sure that you are not inserting `undefined` objects into your array. You can do this with a simple `(object == null)` check. This will capture null and undefined objects.

(2) Filter out undefined objects, e.g. `cartArray = cartArray.filter(item => item != null)`.

Comment: yes am sure that the object is valuable never coming with undefined the whole problem is with an index if I have another way to change object property instead of using index i will do better than filtering everytime cartArray.filter(item => item != null)